# How to fix the regex for this String "#*abc" I want to match this exact string where abc can be any words containing spaces too

Tags: regex

I want to read multiple strings between specific characters from a file using regex. I have tried the following code but could not get expected results.

**My input file contains data in this format:**

```
#*OQL[C++]: Extending C++ with an Object Query Capability

#@José A. Blakeley

#t1995

#cModern Database Systems

#index0

#*Transaction Management in Multidatabase Systems

#@Yuri Breitbart,Hector Garcia-Molina,Abraham Silberschatz

#t1995

#cModern Database Systems

#index1
```

**Expected output:**

```
OQL[C++]: Extending C++ with an Object Query Capability

Transaction Management in Multidatabase Systems
```

**What I tried**

```
    [^#*][a-z]\w+[\n$]
```

It is not reading the string spaces.

Comment: Do you want to catch jst the first line?

Comment: No, basically want to read all text between "#*" and "#@" from the file. My file consists of thousands of records in the mentioned format. I want to be able to read all text between these two characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex. it will catch just after the `#*`, `#c`, `#@`:

```
#[\*c@]\K[\S].*$
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sLLcvE/3)

Comment: Thank you! What about these two? #@José A. Blakeley

Comment: #cModern Database Systems

Comment: Do you want a match for every line which start with `#` and after it every special characters?

Comment: every line in my doc starts with hash but the next char is the key like in above comments I couldn't generate for those two like for its only recognising  #@Jose

Comment: So the char after the `#` can be every char except from letters, digits and spaces?

Comment: yeah in this case #@José A. Blakeley but in #cModern Database Systems its c

Comment: So what is the condition for match or not match?

Comment: like i want to pick the lines that start with #@ and #c

Comment: But what is the permanence? Why `#c` is good, and `#index0` not?

Comment: Because I want to pick only the lines with #c and #@ to convert them to vector and applying cosine similarity on it.

Comment: I've edit my regex. Notice the Demo link. Now it's OK?

Comment: My pleasure. ; )

Comment: That pattern will also match only whitespaces https://regex101.com/r/sLLcvE/1 The tried pattern in the question matches at least 1 char a-z followed by 1+ word chars.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match a `#` and `*` at the start of the string and get what follows, you could use a capturing group. Note to get the characters at the start outside of the character class and escape the `\*`.

To match the space you could use a repeating pattern starting with a space. To match all the words in your example, you could use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to allow which characters to match.

```
^#\*([a-zA-Z][+:a-zA-Z\]\[]+(?: [+:a-zA-Z\]\[]+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jBlPSn/1)

Or as an alternative use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=^#\*)[a-zA-Z][+:a-zA-Z\]\[]+(?: [+:a-zA-Z\]\[]+)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jBlPSn/2)

To match either of the chars you could use a character class

```
^#[*@c]([a-zA-Z][+:a-zA-Z\]\[]+(?: [+:a-zA-Z\]\[]+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jBlPSn/3)

Comment: Thank you bro and what about these two

Comment: #@José A. Blakeley

Comment: #cModern Database Systems

Comment: You could add the characters that you would allow to a character class https://regex101.com/r/jBlPSn/3

Answer (score 2):

Here's the regex you are looking for :

```regex
^#\*(.*)$
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/98SFsX/1)

Explanation:

```
^     // start at the beginning of the line
#\*   // match the literal '#*'
(.*)  // match any character that follows
$     // until the end of the line
```